# Как установить курсор на нужную строку таблицы на html странице?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Страница получает набор строк и с пом. thymeleaf помещает их в таблицу. Нужно, чтобы после заполнения таблицы курсор устанавливался на выбранную строку. Какой н.б. тег вроде: <td active="true"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: я вижу, что с русским у Вас плохо. Прочтите вопрос ещё раз перед тем, как отвечать, дух мой.

Comment: Да. @Духсообщества не прав что использовал Английский язык, но это не повод для сарказма, в конце концов вы спрашиваете вопрос . Для вашей информации, @Духсообщества не давал ответа, а комментировал ваш вопрос . смею заметить очень правильно. Поправте ваш вопрос и добавте кусочек кода где Thymeleaf заполняет таблицу, чтобы ответить правильно. Я только догадываусь что вы спросили про Thymeleaf `th:if` в цикле, но нужен код чтобы подтвердить это . Добро пожаловать на SO.

Comment: я уточню вопрос. есть страница со списком строк в таблице. строка содержит ссылку для перехода на другую страницу с детальным описанием. если перейти на страницу деталей и вернуться обратно, то исходная страница обновляется и теряется "состояние исходной строки". нужно сохранить "активную" строку. напр., 12-я по порядку в общем списке и 3-я сверху в видимой области страницы. мне кажется, с пом. thymeleaf можно исхитриться, но не знаю, как.

Comment: о коде thymeleaf.
список dataset читается из бд с пом. хранимой процедуры и передаётся на станицу с таблицей как model.addAttribute("dataset", dataset);
вот код заполнения таблицы:
                <tr th:each="el, series : ${dataset}" class="table-secondary ms-0">
                    <td class="col-12">
                        <a th:href="@{/spaceMosaicItem/{id}/{cls}(id=${series.index}, cls=${el.getIdClass()})}"
                           th:text="${el.textQuestion}" class="nav-link">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thymeleaf вам конечно поможет, но не будет делать то что вы хотите. Вместо этого броузер сделает всю работу по позиционировании страницы. Как броузер может спозиционировать страницу? Самое простое это букмарк, то есть этот URL ...

```
https://my_website.com/my_page_with_table#my_table_row
```

загрузит страницу с таблицей и спозиционирует её на элементе с Id `my_table_row`.

Теперь все вместе... На вашей странице с таблицей, добавте к каждому линку уникальный Id и для этого Thymeleaf нам поможет, например ...

```
<a th:id="|${series.index}${el.getIdClass()}|" th:href="@{/spaceMosaicItem/{id}/{cls}(id=${series.index}, cls=${el.getIdClass()})}" th:text="${el.textQuestion}" class="nav-link"> </a>
```

Сейчас каждый линк в таблице имеет свой букмарк. Его также можно переместить из линка в строку таблицы `<tr>`, будет лучше позиционировать, на мой взгляд.

Далее, в контроллере вашей страниы с деталями `spaceMosaicItem` когда вы делаете редирект назад на страницу с таблицей, добавте хеш к URL состоящий из параметров ва получили через URL. В нашем случае мы в Thymeleaf скомбенировали `{id}{cls}` и ваш редирект назад будет тот же плюс решетка хаш ...

```
same_url + '#' + id + cls
```

Как-то так по простому. Можно использоать JavaScript, если захотите плавный скроллинг.